# Filters sporadically come up empty

Tags: bug, tag-filters

For example, the [All Metas](https://stackexchange.com/filters/249208/all-metas?sort=newest) filter sometimes returns an empty list of questions.

Sometimes it happens with newest, sometimes with no-answers tab. In a couple of minutes it returns to normal.

Comment: I recently started to get a lot of these: "No questions found" on active or newest filters.

Comment: It's now Jan '19 and the problem persists!

Comment: And it's back affecting SO again today .... been broken since Sunday morning Eastern time.