# Filtered questions not showing any questions from sites where I want to see all questions

Tags: bug, questions, stackexchange.com, tag-filters

Edit: **This problem has disappeared.**  It works as expected now.

**Edit 2018-12-10:** Right now the problem has returned.

---

My [question filter](https://stackexchange.com/filters/63625/favo) is supposed to show all questions from Travel, Academia, Outdoors, Earth Science, and a number of other sites, as well as a selection of tags on Physics, Astronomy, and others.  However, currently it only shows the selection of tags, but not any questions from the sites where I want to see all questions.  The screenshot below only shows questions from Physics, Astronomy, and Bicycles.  I know the other sites, where I want to see all questions, have had questions in the same period.  But they're not shown.

[image: filtered questions screenshot]
(click on image for full-size 1031×6510 pixel screenshot)

Comment: Strange, are you still seeing the same now? I see questions from all the sites if I view the filter myself

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308235/filters-sporadically-come-up-empty

Comment: @Cai No, the problem has disappeared.  Should I close or delete the "question"?

Comment: You should keep it as we noticed the same y'day and this problem seems intermittent. The more data-points the devs have, the easier it becomes to find the root cause.

Comment: The problem is back today.