# Filtered Questions missing PHP activity

Tags: support, bug, tag-filters

When I view my [Favorite Tags](https://stackexchange.com/filters/223126/favorite-tags) the most recent PHP activity on Stack Overflow has been missing from the results for most of the day today. Once in a while a couple of PHP tagged items from Stack Overflow will show up but the majority have not.

I have checked with several browsers and tried a "hard" refresh of the browsers but the results have been the same. Just wondering if there is something going on behind the scenes that may be affecting the flow into Favorites.

Comment: I understand that but my question is about its inclusion in results that are shown via SE not SO.

Comment: That's probably not updated that often.

Comment: It has been consistently updated within minutes of new activity on SO for a very long time. It's just today that I've noticed that it isn't happening which is why I raised the question.

Comment: Related: [Filters sporadically come up empty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308235). As a daily user of Filtered Questions, this has occurred more often recently. Basically, SE sometimes failed returning *all questions on certain tags*, and would show empty if there were no chosen tags.

Comment: FWIW this is still an issue. Less than 10 minutes ago there were no new PHP entries but if one looked at SO directly there were more than 10 new questions.

Comment: And it's happening again this morning. There was a brief burst of SO activity but now nothing again.

Comment: Here we go again ... been broken since yesterday, Sunday Eastern time, morning.