# My filters stopped working - not showing all results

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-filters, filtering, custom-filters

I have a filter that includes tags from three different sites, i.e. StackOverflow, Super User and Sharepoint. The filter has been working fine for years.

Today I find that the results don't return all questions. The results also differ when I go to another page and then reload the filter page.

I either see only results from SharePoint.Stackexchange.com, or I see only results from Stackoverflow and SharePoint. The SuperUser results don't show in the filter at all, although there are new questions for my tags in SuperUser.

What is going on?

I have already logged out, cleared all my cookies that are related to SE/SO and logged in again, but the weird results don't change.

Here is an illustration: The built-in filter for "Favourite Tags" shows only results from the SharePoint site. You can see my favourite tags for SO and the other sites. But all the results are only from SharePoint.
[image]

The newest question in SO tagged with "Excel" was asked half an hour ago and there was a sync after that. This question is not showing in the filter. Why?
[image]

Edit: Eleven hours later. I'm now on a different computer, but logged in with the same account. Same story.

The "Favourite Tags" built-in filter does not show results from the three sites that I have tags in, only results from SuperUser.

My custom filter does not show all sites from my tags filter, only results from StackOverflow

None of the filters right now returns any results from the SharePoint site.

I opened each filter in a new tab in Chrome. Now, when I click the respective other filter in each tab, my custom filter now returns only SuperUser results, and the built-in Favourite Tags filter returns only SharePoint site results.

This just doesn't make sense.

Does anyone have an idea what is causing this? Again, both filters worked fine for years and I've always seen results from all thee sites until this morning.

---

Addressing the [proposed duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308235/filters-sporadically-come-up-empty): I don't think this is the same problem. The symptoms are different. It's not "sporadic", but rather persistent, and it has been presenting that way for 15 hours and not gone away after a couple of minutes. Since the problem just came up with filters that have been working fine for years, I assume that this is a new problem.

Also, if this suddenly affects many people, a bug fix would be great.

**Edit** This problem has now disappeared. I had some difficulty with adding tags, too, so it might be related to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/351166/main-page-of-stackoverflow-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-meta-gives-error/351168#351168).

Comment: Is there some unannounced maintenance going on? Now I have zero results.

Comment: And now I only see results from Stackoverflow. Come on, folks.

Comment: Now I see results from only Super User.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filters sporadically come up empty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308235/filters-sporadically-come-up-empty) (including missing partial tags and/or sites). It's actually an old bug that hasn't been fixed until now.

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. It may be connected, but the symptoms are different. Seeing that his has been going on for almost 24 hrs now and seeing the number of upvotes for this meta question, I gather others have the same problem. It would be great to get a qualified answer instead of a stab in the dark and a pointer to an old unsolved bug. Better yet, how about fixing the bug.

Comment: This might be related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/351168

Comment: @EmilJeřábek That indeed looks to be related. I also had problems adding new tags for SuperUser. Now it seems to be working again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Taryn said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/351168), we had an issue with the tag engine service. It's been resolved now, so filters should be working correctly again.

Thanks for the report!