# Main page of StackOverflow на Русском Meta gives error

Tags: bug, status-completed, russian-stackoverflow

https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/

> [image]

> The data for the tag search is still loading; please retry in a moment.

Comment: I had the exact same issue on Worldbuilding and Physics a few minutes ago, but I thought it was my wifi - looks like it wasn't. Right now it seems back to normal. I'd just been trying to open up the front page.

Comment: I just visited and it works fine for me. I notice your error message says "tag search"; maybe your tag filter is broken; did the site do any kind of tag cleanup, synonymizing, burnination, etc recently?  In any case, best place to dig into is your particular tag filter and see what's going on.

Comment: I'm currently having the same issue on Skeptics Meta.

Comment: I had [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDMsi.png) on [IPS.SE] a few minute ago. Sounds like SE had a bit of an issue

Comment: @BelovedFool still has, based on the review tag.

Comment: Also, I see the [tag:featured] questions are missing from Community Bulletin network wide, guess it's related. /cc @Taryn.

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask Well, at least things are *mostly* working

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The TagEngine across the network got angry and shutdown which resulted in the issue. We're still investigating why it shutdown, but as for now it's back up and running.

Thanks for the report!

Comment: Maybe some rotten tag? ;)